# i need to drawing square and fill it when click the button and take the length from input text to

Tags: java

```
private void text_numActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String nu;
        int a;
        nu=text_num.getText();
        a=Integer.parseInt(nu);
Graphics g1 = contentPane.getGraphics();
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g1;
g2.drawRect(100,100, a, a);
g2.fillRect(100, 100, a, a);
g2.setColor(Color.red);
    }
```

all library is add and its run but when its run give me this error 
run:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
>     at atout.b_sActionPerformed(atout.java:309)
>     at atout.access$100(atout.java:16)
>     at atout$2.actionPerformed(atout.java:69)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
> ```

Comment: You cannot parse an **empty** string into integer.

Comment: `Graphics g1 = contentPane.getGraphics();` is not how you do custom painting in Swing. Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: ok how i can fix it

Comment: If the duplicate answer doesn't help, then consider having a look at [all the other questions on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+Exception+in+thread+%22AWT-EventQueue-0%22+java.lang.NumberFormatException%3A+For+input+string%3A+%22%22)

Comment: `if (nu.trim().length() != 0) { /* convert text */ }`. You should also beware that `Integer.parseInt` will throw an `Exception` and you should be using `try-catch` to handle it

Comment: not give me  error but still not drawing            `private void b_sActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
String nt;
        int a;
        nt=text_num.getText();
        if (nt.trim().length() != 0) {
        a=Integer.parseInt(nt);
Graphics g1 = contentPane.getGraphics();
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g1;
g1.drawRect(140,140, a, a);
g1.fillRect(140, 140, a, a);
g1.setColor(Color.red);

  }
`